# JPA relationship to possibly non-existent object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, many-to-one

For reference, I am using Play! Framework.

I have a JPA Entity that represents data collected by sensors on a device.  Here are the relevant parts of the class declaration:

```
@Entity
public class Data extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    Device dataCollector;

    @ManyToOne
    User user;
}
```

The trouble is, I need to be able to collect data from devices regardless of their being registered in the local database, so there may be devices that have an ID, but the ID is irrelevant to the local database.

The way JPA creates the `Data` table, the column for `dataCollector` is just `Device` IDs.  But when you try to retrieve a record that has an ID for an invalid `Device`, it throws an exception because it can't instantiate a `Device` object.

I could probably solve the problem by simply storing the ID of a `Device` in the `Data` objects, but I really enjoy the clean-ness of JPA creating the object for you.  Is there a way to make JPA give me some default instantiation of `Device` if there is no record for the ID in the `Data` object?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I think if you want to get a Device that is not in your database I think you just can't achieve what you want.

You can instantiate the object, but if you try to send queries to the database it will fail. So, if you want the behavior you gotta store the device then seek the `Data` by `Device` like:

```
List<Data> dataGathered = Data.find("dataCollector = ?", theDataCollector).fetch();
```

That's what I understood about the posts...

Did you get it? or didn't I get what you try?